# Filter SQL query results by aggregrate

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a query that shows the JobIDs where the Worker has not been paid BUT where the Company has been paid.  Below are the table columns and sample data:

```
tblInvoices columns:
-------------------
JobID
InvoiceID
WorkerPaidAmountTotal
CompanyPaidAmountTotal


Sample data
-----------

JobID | InvoiceID | WorkerPaidAmountTotal | CompanyPaidAmountTotal

1         30           100                  150
1         31           0                    100
2         32           0                    75
3         33           25                   50
3         34           10                   30
4         35           0                    0
```

I know how to get the SUM of the amounts paid to either a Worker or the Company.  The results look like this:

---

```
JobID   Worker  Company
1       100     250
2       0       75
3       35      80
4       0       0
```

But what I need are the results of just the JobIDs where the Worker has got 0 and the company >0.  The results I want should be this, but I can't figure out the query to do so:

---

```
JobID   Worker  Company
2       0       75
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `HAVING` clause to filter the groups. Try this :

```
SELECT jobid,
       Worker=Sum(WorkerPaidAmountTotal),
       Company=Sum(CompanyPaidAmountTotal)
FROM   tablename
GROUP  BY jobid
HAVING Sum(WorkerPaidAmountTotal) = 0
       AND Sum(CompanyPaidAmountTotal) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select jobid, worker, company where WorkerPaidAmountTotal = 0 and CompanyPaidAmountTotal
```

Seems to plain to do it... may be i did'nt understand the question